# Serial Port reading with C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am currently working on reading some data from some old machines via Serial Port. At first, I was using .ReadChar() to get my data (an integer number) but my program would randomly freeze and I would get some IO errors, so I thought I would try the ReadAsync() to get my information. But while using ReadAsync, I am getting completely different numbers than what I previously was with ReadChar(). I have tried casting my byte array as int, but I still get weird numbers.

Is there something I am forgetting to do when using ReadAsync?

Here is a code snipit

```
private async void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            await port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4);

            Console.WriteLine("from port1 " + BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer,0));
        }
        catch(Exception w)
        {
            string logPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "TanukiLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message :" + w.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + w.StackTrace + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("An error occured: '{0}'", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you reading 4 bytes at a time because that is how the data is received through the serial port or because `ReadChar` returned an int? `ReadChar` only reads 1 byte.

Comment: Ah, sorry I did not change that back. I originally had it as 1 byte but I was just testing to see if I would get a different result. Even when I only read 1 byte via `ReadAsync` I still get different numbers.

For this serial port, I am expecting numbers between 1-49, but with `ReadAsync` I am getting numbers in the hundreds.

Comment: Do you know the format of the data that you are receiving?  A byte can take on any value from 0-255, it may be the case that you are just interpreting the data incorrectly.

Comment: Just because you ask for 4 bytes to be read that does not mean 4 bytes will be filled in to the `buffer`, you need to read the result of the awaited `ReadAsync` call and keep looping till you have all 4 bytes. Also, reading from `BaseStream` can be problematic due to the inernal buffer inside the `SerialPort` class, I would avoid doing that.

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem. When I used `ReadChar` the data just came in perfectly fine by just using `(int)port.ReadChar()`, but now that I need to define my data format I am not quite sure what to do.

Comment: If the question is "what to do", there are a few sane-looking tutorials in the "serial port read Windows .net" Google results.